# Does SerialDataReceivedEventHandler can be used in SerialPort Communication For Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, serial-port

I have a working windows form application which is able to read data from Serial Port.Now as per my requirement I have to convert it into Windows Service.In my Windows Form Application I used `port1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port1_DataReceived);`  to get data from serial port.

Now as per my requirement i have a question Can I use `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` in windows Service also to get data from serial port.
Here is my code ..

```
port1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port1_Data);
```

Is it the right way to call `port1_Data` method which reads data from serial port..

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling of SerialDataReceivedEventHandler in SerialPort Communication in Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144393/calling-of-serialdatareceivedeventhandler-in-serialport-communication-in-windows)

Comment: @HansPassant  Answer is not available there..

Comment: It is not available here either.  http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins133991.html